# Retrieve data from interactive brokers from inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, networking, port

I have a docker container and a script with the following code:

```
    import backtrader as bt
    import pandas as pd
    
    class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    
        def __init__(self):
            print('initializing strategy')
    
        def next(self):
            print('next')
    
    def start():
        print('starting backtrader')
        cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
    
        store = bt.stores.IBStore(host = '127.0.0.1', port=7497, _debug = True)
        data = store.getdata(dataname='EUR.USD', sectype = 'CASH', exchange = 'IDEALPRO', timeframe = bt.TimeFrame.Seconds)
        print(data.LIVE)
        cerebro.resampledata(data, timeframe = bt.TimeFrame.Seconds, compression = 15)
        


        # spy_prices = pd.read_csv("SPY.csv", index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
        # feed_spy  = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=spy_prices)
        # cerebro.adddata(feed_spy)
    
    
        cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)
        cerebro.run()
    
    start()
```

I am using the paper trading account running on port 7497 and configurations:
[image]

Output of the script above is the following:

```
starting backtrader
4
<error id=-1, errorCode=502, errorMsg=Couldn't connect to TWS.  Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled on the TWS "Configure->API" menu.>
<error id=-1, errorCode=502, errorMsg=Couldn't connect to TWS.  Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled on the TWS "Configure->API" menu.>
<error id=-1, errorCode=502, errorMsg=Couldn't connect to TWS.  Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled on the TWS "Configure->API" menu.>
<error id=-1, errorCode=502, errorMsg=Couldn't connect to TWS.  Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled on the TWS "Configure->API" menu.>
initializing strategy
```

Since the connection with TWS fails, the **def next(self):** is not run. The **def next(self)** is run whenever the data is loaded and for example spy_prices is used.

I think due to the fact that I am working inside a docker container the connection is unsuccessful with these **store = bt.stores.IBStore(host = '127.0.0.1', port=7497, _debug = True)** settings. Should the host be different? Because this is the default host? Or should I map a port inside the docker container?

The dockerfile is the following:

```
# Arguments
ARG IMAGE_VARIANT=slim-buster
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.5

# Base image
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-${IMAGE_VARIANT} as py3

# Working directory
WORKDIR data

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt .

# Pip and apt-get install packages
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc
# Pip install dependencies
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install backtrader
RUN pip install IbPy2

# Remove requirements file, no longer needed
RUN rm requirements.txt
```

Maybe since the TWS (Trader work station of Interactive brokers) is running on port 7947 I have to connect to that port from docker. Doing so by exposing a random port (maybe 7400) and then using docker run -it -p 7400:7497 -v ${PWD}:/data image_name bash and then python main.py.

```
   Add EXPOSE 7400 to docker file
 Changing to: store = bt.stores.IBStore(host = 'host.docker.internal', port=7400, _debug = True)

    Run in terminal: docker run -it -p 7400:7497 -v ${PWD}:/data image_name bash
    Run in terminal/container: python main.py
```

-p 7400:7497 to map the ports. In the end I would like to do something by mayby using docker compose. Because I don't want to work from the terminal but work from VScode.(The proposed method does not work by the way)

Comment: Is the Python script you show running in a container?  (I don't see where it would be `COPY`ed into the image, or the `CMD` that runs it.)  Is the other server running as a subprocess, in a different container, outside a container on the host?

Comment: In the dockerfile the python script is not copied. But it is however copied by using **-v ${PWD}:/data** when the docker file is run in the terminal. In vscode this happens automatically.

The file (**main.py**) is run in the docker terminal **python main.py**

Answer (score 1):

try in code:

```
store = bt.stores.IBStore(host='host.docker.internal', port=7497, _debug=True)
```

in docker:

```
EXPOSE 7497
```

run all:

```
 docker run -it -p 7497:7497 -v ${PWD}:/data your_image_name bash
```

If you're still facing issues. Be sure that:

- The firewall on your host machine allows incoming connections on the TWS port.
- The Docker container is running on the same network as the
  TWS application.